# Why csv.DictWriter is returning only the last row of the dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am really new at python and I'm writing a script to move some data to a CSV file. Data are taken from a dictionary where keys are fixed and values are functions. This is all inside a `for` loop iterating files from which those data are collected.

This is what I've tried:

```
import os, csv

for folder, files in os.walk(directory):
    
     for file in files:
           def name(file):
                name = file.split(".", 1)[0]
           def type(file):
                if file.endswith("a"):
                   return("file_a")
                elif file.endswith("b"):
                   return("file_b")
           def size(file):
                size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(directory,file))
           
           my_dict = {"name": name(file), "type": type(file), "size": size(file)}
      
           with open("csv_file.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_file:
                fieldnames = ("name", "type", "size")
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerows(my_dict)
```

Comment: Calling `csv.DictWriter` returns an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The issue here is that `writer.writeheader()` overwrites the entire file. After each row, you are calling this function that overwrites the entire file, so only the last row will still be there at the end</strike>.

As mentioned in the comments, the actual issue is that you are opening the file with `'w'` permissions in every iteration of the for loop, but you would want to **append** to the file, hence simply replacing `'w'` by `'a'` should give you the wanted result, however, the following solution is still a cleaner approach!

```py
import os, csv

# export opening of the CSV file outside of the loop
# that way it will only be opened once
# use "a" for "append" instead of "w" for write/overwrite
# when you want to add data to an existing file
with open("csv_file.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ("name", "type", "size")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    
    for folder, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
           def name(file):
               name = file.split(".", 1)[0]
           def type(file):
               if file.endswith("a"):
                   return("file_a")
               elif file.endswith("b"):
                   return("file_b")
           def size(file):
                size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(directory,file))
           
           my_dict = {"name": name(file), "type": type(file), "size": size(file)}
           writer.writerows(my_dict)
```

Comment: Writeheader doesn’t overwrite the file.  Opening the file for writing truncates the file.

Comment: You're absolutely right, late night blunder. Editing for clarity.